# What hyperreal functions satisfy this condition involving positive infinitesimals?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-continuity, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

Let $g$ be a function from the hyperreal numbers to the hyperreal numbers which is an extension of a real function in the canonical way, satisfying the condition that for all real numbers $x$ and all positive infinitesimals $\epsilon$, $g(x+\epsilon)=g(x)+\epsilon$.  Then my question is, what condition does the “standard part” of $g$ (i.e. considered as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) satisfy?

Note that the word positive is important; I don’t want it to necessarily hold for negative infinitesimals.  In any case, this is all in service of my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3242046/71829).

Comment: You can define an arbitrary function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ and extend it to the monad of every point through your formula. Is there perhaps a missing assumption on $g$?

Comment: @Wojowu I don’t know whether I’m not stating things properly.  But isn’t it true that if for all real numbers $x$ and all infinitesimals $\epsilon$, there exists an infinitesimal $\delta$ such that $g(x+\epsilon)=g(x)+\delta$, then the standard part of $g$ is continuous?  So I was expecting to get some kind of result like continuity from the right or something stronger for my condition.

Comment: No, that's not true at all.  It's only true for functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which have been extended to the hyperreals in the canonical way.

Comment: @EricWofsey OK, then that’s the extra condition I want to impose on $g$.  “Let $g$ be a real function extended to the hyperreals in the canonical way”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By transfer, if $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $g(a+\epsilon)=g(a)+\epsilon$ is true for all infinitesimal $\epsilon>0$, it must also be true for all sufficiently small real $\epsilon>0$.  So your condition is equivalent to the condition (in the following all variables are real) that for each $x$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $g(x+\epsilon)=g(x)+\epsilon$ for all $0\leq\epsilon<\delta$.  Or, letting $h(x)=g(x)-x$, this means that $h$ is constant in a half-open interval starting at each point.  (So, $\mathbb{R}$ can be partitioned into half-open intervals $[a,b)$ such that $h$ is constant on each one.)

If you removed the positivity condition on $\epsilon$, you would similarly conclude that $h$ is constant in an open interval around each point and thus globally constant since $\mathbb{R}$ is connected, so $g(x)$ would have the form $x+c$ for some constant $c$.

Comment: Suppose that the domain of $g$ is a closed interval $[a,b]$ rather than $(-\infty,\infty)$.  Then would that mean that $[a,b]$ can be partitioned into finitely many half-open intervals such that $h$ is constant on each one?

Comment: No, it might take infinitely many of such intervals.  For instance, the intervals could be like $[0,1/2),[1/2,2/3),[2/3,3/4),\dots$ and then a new interval starting at $1$.

Comment: Hmm, what if we modify the condition like this: for all real numbers $x$, there exists a positive infinitesimal $\delta$ such that for all positive infinitesimals $\epsilon<\delta$, $g(x+\epsilon)=g(x)+\epsilon$?  What would that be equivalent to under the transfer principle?

Comment: That would make no difference.  The point is that any first-order statement which is true of the hyperreals is also true of the reals, so if there exists such a hyperreal $\delta>0$, there exists a real $\delta>0$ with the same property.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying.